# Strange behavior of a FOR loop in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, for-loop

Found a situation for which I can not find an explanation.

I have an array of arrays in objective-c.
this situation the array has 4 empty arrays.

```
NSArray *dados = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
             [[NSArray alloc] init],
             [[NSArray alloc] init],
             [[NSArray alloc] init],
             [[NSArray alloc] init],
             nil];
```

I want a "for" to go through an internal array if it has two or more numbers.

```
for(int i=0; i<((NSArray *)[dados objectAtIndex:1]).count-1;i++){
        NSLog(@"do anything");
    }
```

this "for" enter into infinite loop.
However if I use a "NSLog" tells me that the condition is -1, and the "is" not supposed to happen

```
NSLog(@"%d",((NSArray *)[dados objectAtIndex:1]).count-1);

2014-02-20 15:37:42.563 iKL Time-sheet[31666:a0b] -1
```

how is it possible that this "for" becomes an infinite loop when the stop condition is 0 <-1?

thought to be a curious case, if someone can explain what is going to be able to better understand the language I thanked

---------------------//----------------
answer:

```
for(int i=0; i<(int)(((NSArray *)[dados objectAtIndex:1]).count-1);i++){
            NSLog(@"do anything");
        }
```

with this cast works well, the explanation for this lies in the answer below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`count` is an unsigned integer (`NSUInteger`). When the count is zero, subtracting one wraps, producing a large number. Zero is less than a large number.

Comment: I realize what you are saying, but being so "NSLog" should print a large number. right?

Comment: @NSLog: You told `NSLOG` to expect an `int`, since that is what the `%d` conversion specifier means. You passed it an unsigned integer. It happened to reinterpret the bits of the unsigned integer as if they were the bits of an `int`, and it printed the value that an `int` **would have** if it had those bits. That is not the value that an `NSUInteger` has when encoded with those bits.

Answer (score 2):

your code is not obvious i would re-write with fast iteration

```
NSArray *dados = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
         [[NSArray alloc] init],
         [[NSArray alloc] init],
         [[NSArray alloc] init],
         [[NSArray alloc] init],
         nil];

for(NSArray * a in dados)
{
    if([a count] >1)
    {
        NSLog(@"do something");
    }
}
```

edit:

or

```
@synchronized(dados){

    for(int i=0; i<[dados count]);i++){
       if([[dados objectAtIndex:i]count]>1)
       NSLog(@"do anything");
    }
}
```

because you for loop wont make it to the end... you are combining two tests that logically cant be combined... unless your array was sorted by number of elements first.

Comment: He may need to know the index he is currently at

Comment: this code does not work because I know exactly what's inside that array I want to go. my problem is when it is empty for all other cases the code above is well

Comment: @pedro... not 100% sure what you mean... but replace the `if()` with one that makes sense... and if you know you dont need to loop anymore then `break`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the -1 from count, otherwise even if you array has many objects it will always **skip the last element**.

```
for(int i=0; i<((NSArray *)[dados objectAtIndex:1]).count-1;i++){
        NSLog(@"do anything");
}
```

Comment: I want it to skip the last

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *dados = @[@[],@[],@[]];

// I want a "for" to go through an internal array
// if it has two or more numbers (skipping the last one)
for( NSUInteger idx = 0;
     (dados[1].count >= 2) && (idx < dados[1].count - 1);
     idx++) 
{
    NSLog(@"do anything");
}
```